# Problems with uploading Node.js server to FIrebase Functions

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'd really like some help with uploading a Node.js code to Firebase, to be a server for my Android app.

**What I need to do:**
I'm developing an app and pretty much the only thing that's left for me to do is uploading my server, which is written in Node.js, to the cloud. For that purpose, I'm using Firebase Cloud Functions.

**What I have:**
Following tutorials I found online, I have followed these steps:

- Opened a Firebase project.
- Wrote Node.js code for my server (which works well on local host).
- Installed Firebase Tools with `npm install -g firebase-tools`.
- Logged in, initiated and deployed a Function, getting this result:

[image]

Throughout the process, I mainly followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@sandun.isuru/how-to-deploy-nodejs-express-app-to-firebase-as-function-31515c304e70) and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOeioOKUKI8). In addition to some tutorials in the Firebase documentation.

**What my problem is:**
Well, in the console I see only this:
[image]

The URL in the picture (below the "Trigger" headline) doesn't work for me, unfortunately, and I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong. The server worked just fine in localhost before I tried uploading it in the first place. In addition, my access to the Firebase Realtime Database has stopped working as well - and it did work well before.

**Some code:**
Here's some relevant parts of my Node.js code (which I wrote in the `index.js` file):

```
...
// Post request for sending token to server:
app.post('/token', (req, res, next) => {
    // Get token from user:
    let token = req.body.token;
    if (!token) return res.status(400).json({err: "missing token"});
    console.log(`Received save token request from ${req.params.user} for token=${token}`);

    // Put it as a value in the JSON object 'tokens' with the user's username as key:
    tokens[req.params.user] = token;
    res.status(200).json({msg: "saved ok"});
});
...
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

The rest is mostly more of the same, in addition to all the necessary `require`s and all that.

Here's my `firebase.JSON`:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]

  }
}
```

And in my Android client, here's an example of how I call an HTTP request (corresponding to the `POST` function I posted above):

```
_queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
                token = instanceIdResult.getToken();
                getUser(token);
                JSONObject requestObject = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    requestObject.put("token", token);
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG_MAINACTIVITY, token);
                }
                JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, REQUEST_URL + "token",
                        requestObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.i(TAG_MAINACTIVITY, "Token saved successfully");
                    }
                },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Log.e(TAG_MAINACTIVITY, "Failed to save token - " + error);
                            }
                        });

                _queue.add(req);
            }
        });
```

I tried several variations of the request URL, currently it's this:
`https://emotional-clarity-9ced0.web.app/`

**Main issues:**

- I'm unsure what URL I should use to access my functions. As I said, the one in the picture I provided doesn't work, nor do several variations of it which I tried using.
- I cannot be sure that my upload process was even correct in the first place. As I said, I followed the tutorials which I linked quite closely. It shows no errors throughout the process, yet when trying to send an HTTP request from my client, I receive no response.

Being completely honest, I have zero idea what I'm missing here, and I obviously am missing something. Nothing I found online helped me. So I'd really appreciate if any of you could please shed some light on what I'm doing wrong because it's my first experience with these types of things.

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to be clear about what isn't working the way you expect.  Your question should include debugging details that help narrow down the scope of the problem.  Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Added some more specific questions.

Comment: I tested https://emotional-clarity-9ced0.web.app/token with Postman and got {
    "err": "missing token"
} so you deployed the function correctly.

Comment: Is it possible that my problem is with how I send the http requests from my Android client then?

Comment: @DougStevenson Wait, is it possible that I can't send API requests through Firebase Cloud Functions if I only use the free-tier plan?

Comment: No, it's not an issue with the free tier. Please explain what you're trying to do exactly, expected results and actual results, and the output of the Logs in your provided code.

Comment: I see this as part of my logs: `Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions` so yeah I think that the free tier is a problem. I'm trying to access some external API functions. I started getting some of the results I was expecting, except for functions that involve such external API.

Comment: Maybe you want to see how to [Enable Billing in GCP](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#enable_billing_for_a_project).

Comment: @KevinQuinzel Oh, it's a school project... I ain't paying a penny for that. But thanks.

Comment: Got it. For future references it might be useful :)

Comment: @KevinQuinzel For sure! Thanks mate. I'll look for another cloud service in the meantime.